# NoMethodError (R Function "get" not found)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, nomethoderror

I'm trying to connect Ruby and R, using RSRuby.

In my application_controller I have the following:

```
def InitR
    @r = RSRuby.instance
    return @r
end
```

When I make:

```
@r = InitR()
```

It raises the following in the browser: **R Function "get" not found**

and in console it shows:

```
NoMethodError (R Function "get" not found):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `InitR'
  app/controllers/diagnostic_controller.rb:32:in `generatePdf'
```

I have tried to change stack limit as I have seen in some posts, but it seems to do nothing.

### Does anyone know something?

This is how my code shows in my ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  # Make R instance available to all
  def initR
    @r = RSRuby.instance
  end

 end
```

And here is the DiagnosticController, where I want to use the instance:

```
def generatePdf
    project = Project.find(session[:project_id])

    pdf = Prawn::Document.new

    sentence = RSentence.find_by_name("library").content.gsub("LIBRARY", "lattice")

    pdf.text sentence

    pdf.render_file project.name.to_s + ".pdf"

    @r = initR
    @r.eval_R(sentence)

    redirect_to :controller => "diagnostic", :action => "index" 
  end
```

The exception raises when calling RSRuby.instance

Comment: @Why do to talk about `stack limit` here? The error dosen't suggest this..can you run this for example `require 'rsruby' @r = RSRuby.instance
@r.rnorm(100)`

Comment: I am able to run that code with no problem from the rails console. However, in the application, the RSRuby.instance raises the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. You're using a capital in your def, InitR - should be initR
2. You're trying to set the instance variable to itself, i.e. inside and outside the InitR method.

try

```
def initR
  @r = RSRuby.instance
end
```

then just call initR, which will instantiate @r

you can the access functions using @r  e.g. `@r.wilcox_text([1,2,3],[4,5,6])`

OK, following your update, it looks like the initR function is defunct.  Setting `@r = initR`, is the like saying `@r = @r = RSRuby.instance`, e.g. you've called it twice.  if you want to use the function change it to

```
def initR
  RSRuby.instance
end
```

You can then call `@r = initR`

Also, it looks at though the error relates to R itself, i.e the error isn't a Ruby error, but an R error.  Could you try running the steps in your generate function in a rails console, this may highlight which particular step is failing.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I have tried this, but it raises the same exception.

Comment: can you post some more of the code from your controller?  it may be context related

Comment: I have found a fix for the issue. It is related to the lack of required stack memory for the selected application process. In my case I had to run this command: `ulimit -s unlimited` before spawning the application process. But I would recommend to not leave it as unlimited in production.

Comment: @PawelBarcik, increasing the stack size did not work for me... Is there anything else that you found that can solve this issue?